# how can I convert this regex lookbehind to be js safe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, regex-lookarounds

In the below code I have r = my regex. Which then gets tested against given s strings to look for matches which find the first included substring between an @ and whitespace, where @ must either start the test string or it must follow whitespace.

```js
const test = (s) => {
  let r = /(?<=^@|\s@)[^\s]+/g;
  let a = r.exec(s);
  if (a)
    console.log(`given: ${s}, found: ${a[0]}`);
  else
    console.log(`given: ${s}, no match found.`);
}

test("@abc"); // match = 'abc'
test("abc @def"); // match = 'def'
test("abc@def"); // no match
test("@abc@def"); // match = 'abc@def'
test("abc@def @ghi"); // match = 'ghi'
test("abd def"); // no match
test("@abd @def"); // match = 'abc' (only)
```

The problem is while this works in Chrome it does not work in Firefox giving (SyntaxError: invalid regexp group) and so the ?<= lookbehind is not js safe.  Can test this by opening chrome and firefox, going to codepen.io. pasting code into the JS area.  And view the codepen console in Chrome (will see results) and the Firefox dev tools console will see the error and no results in codepen console.

Can someone advise how I might convert this to be js safe but still work the same.

*Note (?:^@|\s@)[^\s]+ is close but it match contains the @ and any leading whitespace. (yes could be easily replaced but am wondering if there is a js safe way of doing this).*

Comment: I'm assuming that by `match = 'abc' (only)` you mean `match = 'abd' (only)` only? (there's no `abc` in the last input string)

Comment: well spotted @CertainPerformance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of lookbehind, use a non-capturing group instead for the `@`. Then, capture the following non-space characters in a group. With your match object, if it's not null, printing the `[1]`st index will give you the contents of that capturing group.

Make sure not to use the global flag (at least, not with this implementation) - with `/g`, you'll get an array of all *full matches*, but no information on captured groups.

Also note that `[^\s]` simplifies to `\S` (any non-whitespace character):

```js
const test = (str) => {
  const regex = /(?:^@|\s@)(\S+)/;
  const match = str.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    console.log(`given: ${str}, found: ${match[1]}`);
    }
  else
    console.log(`given: ${str}, no match found.`);
}

test("@abc");          // match = 'abc'
test("abc @def");      // match = 'def'
test("abc@def");       // no match
test("@abc@def");      // match = 'abc@def'
test("abc@def @ghi");  // match = 'ghi'
test("abd def");       // no match
test("@abd @def");     // match = 'abc' (only)
```